# How do I install ubuntu on blank harddisk

Tags: grubrescue

I want to install ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop

1. I have a internal hard drive with a case which has been formatted with NFTS file system
2. I have a live Pendrive with ubuntu 20.04 LTS
3. And a laptop with no harddisk

Now when I try to boot my laptop with the formatted harddisk installed inside the laptop it shows `unknown filesystem grub rescue`

So should I boot ubuntu using live PD without harddisk and then install ubuntu on it? 
Will it solve the `grub` issue?
I have already tried doing `ls (hd0,msdos1)` etc. 
It still shows `unknown filesystem`
Please help.

Comment: Actually my HDD was running ubuntu 18.04 but suddenly had some problems while booting so I made a Boot Pendrive and took my imp data into another drive and formatted the drive which was running ubuntu and while formatting it asked me which filesystem would I prefer as I am a noob I  chose NTFS

Comment: @user535733 You got any solution for this mess?

Comment: What mess? You have not described a mess. Install Ubuntu. If it fails to install, then give us details about exactly what failed.

Comment: So I should install ubuntu on my hdd right?

Comment: Just being sure 

Comment: Sure, what have you got to lose?

Comment: Ubuntu cannot use NTFS, so you need to either choose use entire drive, erasing the NTFS or manually delete that partition so drive is not partitioned at all. If UEFI you also need gpt partitioning & an ESP- efi system partition. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was happening because the hdd was totally Empty.
This worked for me:-
Boot using the flash drive 
Just connect your hdd using the case
Install the Ubuntu on your driver
Shutdown your PC 
Install the HDD inside the lappy
And start the laptop